# Open domain in general topology

Tags: general-topology

A subset of a topological space is an open domain if it is equal to the interior of its closure. Show that if U is the interior of a closed set, then it is an open domain. Futhermore, show that the intersection of two open domains is an open domain.

Any ideias?

Comment: did you think of the interior of the closure of U?

Comment: Such  a set is also called a regular-open set. A closed set that is the closure of its interior is called a regular-closed set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part 1:** Let $Z$ be a closed set, and $U = \text{Int}(Z)$. We want to show $U$ is the interior of its closure.

Since $Z$ is a closed set containing $U$, $\overline{U} \subset Z$, and so $\text{Int}(\overline{U}) \subset \text{Int}(Z) = U$. On the other hand, since $U$ is an open set contained in $\overline{U}$, $U \subset \text{Int}(\overline{U}))$.

**Part 2:** Let $U$ and $V$ be open domains. We want to show $(U \cap V)$ is the interior of its closure. Since $U \cap V$ is an open set contained in $\overline{U \cap V}$, $U \cap V \subset \text{Int}(\overline{U \cap V})$. On the other hand, since $\overline{U \cap V} \subset \overline{U}$, $\text{Int}(\overline{U \cap V}) \subset \text{Int}(\overline{U}) = U$. For the same reason, $\text{Int}(\overline{U \cap V}) \subset V$. So $\text{Int}(\overline{U \cap V}) \subset U \cap V$.

Answer (score 1):

A well known identity for interiors and closures is, for all $A$ a subset of a topological space:

$$\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(A) = \operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(A)$$

I proved it in [my note here](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/24.pdf) as formula (p).

This implies your statement immediately as we can write the interior of a closed set $S$ as $\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}(S)$.

Comment: @Mirko I also gave the general formula from which the fact follows. The other answer did not.

Comment: That’s a nice write-up in the note you mention. Bookmarked. +1 for that alone

Comment: @MPW thx, it was fun writing it too.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Nice. I don't know if you've already been told, or if there even is some use to pointing out, but there is a typo in point (q), end of page 2: where it says "$p'')$ applied to $-$", it should rather be "$p'')$ applied to $1$".

Comment: @G.Sassatelli It's kind of hard to update it now, the site's a bit inactive. But I'll keep it in mind if I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

$Int(S)=Int(\bar{S})$ for any closed set $S$.

So what do you know about closure of $U$?

Comment: Just to say that closure of a closed set is the same set and hence interiors match